# How to determine if a day comes in PST or PDT in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I am creating a date in node js, my server is in IST, I want to determine if the date would come PDT or PST (i.e. If the Daylight saving is on or off). If my server was in PST/PDT time it would be automatically decide. Is there any way I can determine this?

Comment: Not for future dates. The rules can change.

Comment: how about past dates? when i create new Date("dateString") it's able to decide PST or PDT if my system time is in PT. I want to do the same from IST system time.

Comment: The answer in the dup post is one way.  Another would be using the `isDST` function from [moment.js](http://momentjs.com)

Answer (score 0):

After creating the date with `...Date()` you are able to retrieve the timezone offset of the client with `...getTimezoneOffset()`. You can not tell whether the client is in DST or not, but you have the absolute amount to GMT/UTC. Or, you can further retrieve the time a UTC timestamp and convert that to whatever you want on the server.

Comment: I will get a date string "10/23/2014 00:00:00" that is from PT. I send to a client which may be in any time zone but i want to determine that day on PT was daylight saving on or not.

Comment: Convert to UTC timestamp in milliseconds, send that to the client and create the date from  milliseconds instead of a formatted string. Whatever timezone with or w/o DST the client is in, the date will be proper, since it's set from UTC: `ndate = new Date(); ndate.setTime(UTCinMillisFromServer);`

Comment: What if the local machine is in a different timezone (not PST or PDT)?

Comment: Actually that doesn't matter at all: submit UTC and the client will transform in his TZ, regardless which one this is and whether it has or not DST etc.